# open shelve file

Tags: python

I'm trying to lookup for a "key" in "my.db". I did the following:

```
import shelve
db_file = os.path.join(self.path_data, 'my_directory', 'my.db')
s = shelve.open(db_file)
val = s["key"]
```

and I get this error:

```
 /opt/Python-2.4.3/lib/python2.4/shelve.py in open(filename='/path_here/dir/netmhcpan.db', flag='c', protocol=None, writeback=False, binary=None)
 /opt/Python-2.4.3/lib/python2.4/shelve.py in __init__(self=<DbfilenameShelf instance>, filename='/path_here/dir/netmhcpan.db', flag='c', protocol=None, writeback=False, binary=None)
 /opt/Python-2.4.3/lib/python2.4/anydbm.py in open(file='/path_here/dir/netmhcpan.db', flag='c', mode=438)
......
ImportError: No module named _bsddb
  args = ('No module named _bsddb',)
```

Appreciate any help to solve this problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install `db4-devel` or the like, then rebuild Python.

Comment: It works fine when I do it in python command line, but fails inside a class.

Comment: @DGT:  "but fails inside a class."  A completely different question.  Accept this answer.  Open a new question.