# "ImportError: No module named _bsddb" when opening shelve in Docker container

Tags: python, docker, bsddb

I want to open a [shelve](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shelve.html) inside a Docker container based in Python's official image, [python:2.7.9-wheezy](https://registry.hub.docker.com/_/python/). But I get an import error.

```
syncer/util.py:19: in get_from_shelve
    db = shelve.open(conf.SHELVE_LOCATION)
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/shelve.py:239: in open
    return DbfilenameShelf(filename, flag, protocol, writeback)
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/shelve.py:223: in __init__
    Shelf.__init__(self, anydbm.open(filename, flag), protocol, writeback)
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/anydbm.py:84: in open
    mod = __import__(result)
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dbhash.py:7: in <module>
    import bsddb
...
E           ImportError: No module named _bsddb
```

On my host machine the problem isn't there and `_bsddb` is located at
`/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_bsddb.so`. This file is also available in my Docker container, so I don't understand why it can't be imported.

[Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5812184/1073222) suggest to install `db4-devel`, but this package isn't available in my container.

How do I open the shelve in the Docker container?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you need the `libdb4.8-dev` package ([link](https://github.com/utahta/pythonbrew/issues/59)), but unfortunately this is no longer available since Lucid.

I have found some possible solutions:

1. `sudo apt-get install libdb5.1++-dev` ([link](https://github.com/litecoin-project/litecoin/issues/47#issuecomment-17201792))
2. Installing `libdb4.8++` from the Lucid repository ([link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/290094/libdb4-8-is-no-longer-available))
3. `sudo apt-get install libdb++-dev libminiupnpc-dev` ([link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/393289/how-to-install-libdb4-8-dev-or-equivalent-on-13-10), might require reinstalling Python though)

Hope it helps!

(I'm on the train right now, so will definitely test them for you later)

---

EDIT: Also [this page](https://www.jcea.es/programacion/pybsddb.htm) gives a lot of information about supported versions.

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't work for me. For now I use [google/python](https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/google/python/). But this image doesn't contains Python 2.7.9, instead it's shipped with Python 2.7.2